# Recommended laptop model of Dell Vostro for running Ubuntu 12.x

Tags: dell, dell-vostro

Which is the recommended laptop model for Dell Vostro. Is it 2420 or 2520 or 3560, which is the latest?

I currently have 2420, 2520 as well and I am having lots of issues with wireless drivers for 2520. I just need to know which machine is better for software development

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic ,see the topics where this forum is NOT the place for.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about shopping recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

I currently have Dell Vostro 3560 running Ubuntu 12.04 and I am having no issue as of now regarding Wi-Fi. I am also a software engineering student and I have no trouble running g++, java.

About the latest version I think 3560 is the latest. You can also go to dell official website to find out more about the version of laptops.

Comment: What advantages are there in 3560 compared to 2420 or 2520 laptops? I don't need a powerful graphics option.